# mount command not working in a bash function

Tags: macos, bash

This is in MacOS 10.11.6

in the terminal using bash, I can issue the following command and it works perfectly.

```
mount -t $FILESYS //$USERNAME:$PASSWORD@$SERVER/$DSKLBL ~/$MOUNTPOINT
```

I can also include in a bash script and it works perfectly.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILESYS=smbfs
USERNAME=myusername
PASSWORD=mypassword
SERVER=myserverip
DSKLBL=mysharepoint
MOUNTPOINT=mymountpoint

echo Attempting to Mount $MOUNTPOINT
mount -t $FILESYS //$USERNAME:$PASSWORD@$SERVER/$DSKLBL ~/$MOUNTPOINT
ERR=$?

exit
```

However if I take that same command in put it into a function, it fails. I get Segmentation fault errors.
It looks something list this...

```
#!/bin/bash

FILESYS=smbfs
USERNAME=myusername
PASSWORD=mypassword
SERVER=myserverip
DSKLBL=mysharepoint
MOUNTPOINT=mymountpoint

mount_share () {
     echo Attempting to Mount $MOUNTPOINT
     mount -t $FILESYS //$USERNAME:$PASSWORD@$SERVER/$DSKLBL ~/$MOUNTPOINT
     ERR=$?
}

mount_share

exit
```

This works perfectly in Ubuntu Linux 20.04 LTS
Any ideas why this fails? Does it have anything to do with the current shopt config?

Comment: Would you mind adding the exact error that the script is generating?

Comment: It just says Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: In that case add the `-v` flag to your `mount` command to enable verbose output and edit your question with the full error message.

Comment: What happens if you put curly braces around each of the parameter names to be expanded (e.g. `$USERNAME` becomes `${USERNAME}`) so that the shell knows not to try to interpret the colon, at-sign, etc as part of parameter expansion?

Comment: "Segmentation fault", if not handled, leads to termination of the process. Which of your processes gets terminated because of segfault? `mount` or `bash`? If `bash`, does it terminate when the function is defined or when it's called? (`echo foo` just before calling the function may help). If `bash`, what is the version of it? (`bash --version`). If `bash`, does [quoting right](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618) help? (you should quote right anyway).

Comment: I found the problem. I had pulled the script from another one of my computers and had to add PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin for it to work. Now it's not required and was causing the problem.

Comment: @user410596 No, you did not find the problem, you found a way around it. `mount` should not segfault if you have a slightly different `PATH`